# Outlook / Office365 - flag emails sent to a specific address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a email address: `me@original-domain.com`
I also some aliases: `me@new-domain.com` and `me@alias-domain.com`

`original-domain.com` is linked to an old business and I want to stop using `me@original-domain.com` so that I can eventually cancel that domain.

My first problem is that I have over ten years of subscriptions, bills and other things sent to that email. I also have about 5 years of the same sent to `me@new-domain.com`. BUT my MAIN problem is that even if an email is sent to `me@new-domain.com` or `me@alias-domain.com`, Outlook will show it as if it was sent to the primary mailbox address of `me@original-domain.com`.

The question is: is there a rule that that can do something with an email based on which address it was SENT to and not what it was RECEIVED at?

Comment: One of the Advanced Rules allow Sent to and then the sent to domain can be edited. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: is there a rule that that can do something with an email based on which address it was SENT to and not what it was RECEIVED at?

I'm afraid that it's not available. We can only create a rule for the emails in Inbox with the below condition:
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.